# Force Content-Type on files with no Extension in EclipsePDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I use Eclipse-PDT to work on my PHP projects and find it inconvenient when Eclipse does not recognize my php files that have no extension. Our project contains many cli/bash-style php scripts that have no file-extension (for whatever reason). This results in no code-completion, highlighting, etc for these particular files. It treats them as plain-text.

Is there a way I can mark these particular files as PHP to use the PDT features?

Comment: If it is possible (I personally do not know), you would be writing a rule that would affect all files and not just the php files. Seems like it would get messy.

Comment: Related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46297

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you might be able to do something like this :

- right-click on the file in the Navigator panel -- or the equivalent you are using
- choose `Open with` > `Other...`
- In the dialog box that pops-up, you should be able to choose the `PHP Editor`

Next time you'll double-click on that file to open it, it should automatically bge opened using the editor you selected earlier.

But you'll have to do that once for each one of your files, so Eclipse PDT does know for which files which editor it should use...

Comment: That's actually what I would prefer. I'd like to avoid any blanket configuration changes. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: After opening the extensionless file with the PHP Editor I am presented a dialog that states `Unsupported content type in the editor` and it suggests I edit content types in the config menu. Oh well, sounded promising.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround suggested by Swooper (in his case for perl) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177212/210336) suggests to create links to the files with extensions and edit the files in Eclipse through those links.

Not ideal and maybe hard if you have a lot of extensionless files, but it will work.