# Eclipse syntax highlighting on extensionless files?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ide, syntaxhighlighter

I have a perl CGI script that needs to have a specific extensionless filename to run correctly from the software that uses it. I'm using Eclipse 3.7.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 Linux as my IDE, and it's not highlighting syntax on the file nor using the limited autocomplete features (like adding a second closing tag for things like quotes and various brackets). Right click> properties on the file reveals that the OS seems to know it's a perl script, but Eclipse evidently does not. Can I somehow tell Eclipse to use the perl syntax highlighter for all extensionless files? Or, failing that, for this specific file?

Comment: related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46297

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to this, thought I might throw it in here if someone has a similar problem later and runs into this.

What I did was create a link to the script, and gave the link a .pl extension. This happily caused Eclipse to parse the syntax correctly. Problem solved.